# GoogleMap.moveCamera not working after coming back from child activity

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a GoogleMap in a SupportMapFragment. It works fine in the initial display. The camera is moved, and a circle is added. But the moveCamera and addCircle stop working after coming back from its child activity.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    Log.d("Main Activity",
            "onConnected called");      

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);
    // Display the connection status
        Location loc = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();


        mGeolocation = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(),loc.getLongitude());
        Log.d("GeoLocation",
                "latitue:"+mGeolocation.latitude+" longitude:" + mGeolocation.longitude);   

        if(mMap.getMyLocation()==null)
            Log.d("GeoLocation",
                    "mMap location not set yet");   
        else    
            Log.d("GeoLocation",
                "mMap location-----latitue:"+ mMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude()+" longitude:" + mMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude());   

        CameraPosition targetPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(mGeolocation)
        .zoom(12.0f)
        .bearing(0)
        .tilt(25)
        .build();


        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(targetPosition));

        CircleOptions circleParam = new CircleOptions()
                                    .center(mGeolocation)
                                    .radius(MAX_DISTANCE)
                                    .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
                                    .strokeWidth(5)
                                    .visible(true);

        mMap.addCircle(circleParam);

}
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    Vendor v = listedVendors.get(marker.getId());
    if( v!=null){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_VENDOR, v);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_GEO, mGeolocation);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CURRENTADDRESS, mCurrentAddress);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    Log.d("Main Activity",
            "OnPause called");      
    super.onPause();
    if (mLocationClient != null) {
        mLocationClient.disconnect();
    }`
}
```

The onCameraChange event is not called either.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: In which method are you attempting to connect to the GoogleApiClient? My guess would be that the GoogleMap is being instantiated again when you return to the initial Activity, therefore, the instance you got configured is different from the one is visible when you return

Comment: Do you see the `onConnected called` log when you return to the Map Activity?  It's possible that the API is still connected, and does not need to be re-connected.  Can you show the code where you start the child Activity?

Comment: It was called in onResume from where I call the connect method of the LocationClient. The LocationClient was disconnected in the onPause. the connect method will trigger the onConnected callback when the location service is connected.

Comment: I can see the logs in the onConnected, and I am able to debug into the method. I don't see anything unusual, but the camera just doesn't move.

Answer (score 1):

OK! Finally, I figured out the problem by myself. Somehow, I declared the mLocationClient as a static member of the activity

private static LocationClient mLocationClient;

The problem is caused by the "static" (I don't know why. Since it is private, it should be the same except the way they are accessed). After removing the 'static' attribute from the above statement, everything works fine now.